# Azure AD B2C strips html tags from Custom UI template

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

While trying to customise the unified (Sign In & Sign Up page), I have this simple HTML in my unified.html template (fragment):

```
<div class="col-4 login-box gradient-background">
  <div>
    <h1>WELCOME TO<br/>SuperFancyProductName<sup>&reg;</sup></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="api" data-name="Unified"></div>
</div>
```

However, when Azure AD B2C renders the Sign In page, the  element is stripped of from inside the h1 element, with this result (fragment):

```
<div>
  <h1>WELCOME TO<br>SuperFancyProductName®</h1>
</div>
```

In our case, this does not allow us to properly align the ® symbol.

Is there any documentation on what tags are allowed in the template html and how this template transformation actually works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a subset of HTML that is allowed but is not documented.

[image]

It looks like the superscript tag is not allowed here. For reference, see [this Github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9564).

The docs team is still working on an update to show what's allowed.

You can upvote some of the requests in User Voice or create your own request: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/31173091-improve-the-tag-filtering-on-the-b2c-custom-ui-tem